# How to implement recursive function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Below defines an Algebraic Data Type IntList :

```
data IntList = Empty | Cons Int IntList
```

The function intListProd computes the product of IntList type :

```
intListProd :: IntList -> Int
intListProd Empty      = 1
intListProd (Cons x l) = x * intListProd l
```

But I'm unsure how to create IntList type.

I've tried :

```
*Main> let x = Cons 3
*Main> :t x
x :: IntList -> IntList
```

But how to create type IntList so as to invoke intListProd ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Cons` cell contains two things: an element and a tail. If the list is only supposed to contain one element, the tail is empty (represented by the nullary constructor `Empty`). So to represent a list containing 3 as its only element, you use:

```
let x = Cons 3 Empty
```

Then `:t x` will be `IntList`.

Comment: what is the use of "data IntList = Empty | Cons Int IntList" as "data IntList = Empty | Cons Int" is same data type ?

Comment: @blue-sky The use it that it can represent lists of arbitrary sizes by nesting multiple cons cells. The latter definition would only allow list of zero or one elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new data type:

`data IntList = Empty | Cons Int IntList`

This basically create you 2 data contructor function:

```
> :t Empty
Empty :: IntList

> :t Cons
Cons :: Int -> IntList -> IntList
```

So the first returns an IntList type and the second need 2 parameters ( Int and IntList) and return an IntList.

In your binding you just partially apply `Cons` function, giving it just 1 param :

```
*Main> let x = Cons 3
```

and this is asking you for another IntList to be a complete type.
Now, you can obtain an IntList in 2 ways (because you have 2 constructors for this type):

```
Cons 3 (Empty)
```

or

```
Cons 3 (Cons a b) --where a is an Int and b is IntList.
```

Now for the second, b can be Empty or Const a' b':

```
Cons 3 (Cons 1 (Empty))
```

or

```
Cons 3 (Cons 2 (Cons 1 (Empty))) -- 3 2 1 could be any Int number.
```

Let's now take a closer at type of the second one:

```
Cons Int ( Cons Int ( Cons Int ( IntList)))
```

Remember Cons takes an Int and an IntList and returns an IntList ?

```
Cons Int ( Cons Int ( IntList)) --Now doing the same we came up to
Cons Int (IntList) -- Once more
IntList
```

That means our construction `Cons 3 (Cons 2 (Cons 1 (Empty)))` have type of `IntList` and can be used to apply `intListProd` computation over it.

Comment: so for the statement "data IntList = Empty | Cons Int IntList" , specificall the "data IntList" section defines the return type for each of the constructors, in this case IntList ?

Comment: @blue-sky exactly, data IntList is the return and Const Int IntList is a function "Const" which takes 2 params "Int" and "IntList" and return an IntList (because of data IntList)